# DESCRIPTION "Authors@R" field for organizations

Tags: r, metadata, documentation

What's the proper way to represent an organization in the `Authors@R` field of an R package's `DESCRIPTION` file?  I didn't find an answer in the following places:

## R Packages book

http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#author mentions it only tangentially when discussing roles in the field:

> `cph`: copyright holder.  This is used if the copyright is held by someone other than the author, typically a company (i.e. the author’s employer).

However, there's no mention of whether/how a `person` entity should still be created in this case, or whether there's an alternative approach.

## Writing R Extensions docs

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file doesn't mention organizations.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer in the `person` function docs:

> For persons which are not natural persons (e.g., institutions, companies, etc.) it is appropriate to use `given` (but not `family`) for the name, e.g., `person("R Core Team", role = "aut")`.

In my case, I'll do it like this:

```
Authors@R: c(
  person("My Organization, Inc.", role=c("aut", "cre", cph)),
  person("Ken", "Williams", role="cre"))
```

Comment: @RalfStubner it's probably a good idea to be unique (and also to add an email address for `cre`), but I haven't found anything official stating it needs to be.

Comment: Writing R Extensions says: *The mandatory ‘Maintainer’ field should give a single name followed by a valid [...] email address [...]  For a CRAN package it should be a person, not a mailing list and not a corporate entity*. It further states *Both ‘Author’ and ‘Maintainer’ fields can be omitted if a suitable ‘Authors@R’ field is given. [...]  ‘"cre"’ (creator) for the package maintainer [...] The ‘Author’ and ‘Maintainer’ fields are auto-generated from it if needed when building or installing.* So it is necessary if the `Maintainer` field is not separately defined.